# Очистить лист не трогая защищенные ячейки

Tags: excel, vba

Добрый день. Помогите с макросом. Нужен макрос, который очистит все незащищенные заполненные ячейки на листе. Лист при этом защищен паролем.
Я вот такое нашел, но ругается на "uss.Select". Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
    Sub Clear()
        Dim ss As Range, uss As Range
        For Each ss In Selection
           If Not ss.Locked Then
               If uss Is Nothing Then
                   Set uss = ss
               Else
                   Set uss = Union(uss, ss)
               End If
           End If
        Next
        uss.Select
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uss.Select
```

Этой строкой Вы выделяете незащищенные ячейки ранее выделенного диапазона (*In Selection* - в выделенном). Но нужно же удалить данные:

```
 uss.ClearContents
```

Если в выделенном диапазоне не окажется ни одной незащищенной ячейки, Ваш код вывалится в ошибку. Нужно проверять заполнение диапазона:

```
If Not uss Is Nothing Then uss.ClearContents
```

Макрос работает с выделенным диапазоном. Если нужно очистить все незащищенные ячейки на листе, можно работать с *UsedRange* - пользовательским диапазоном.

Код можно сократить, если заранее известна хоть одна ячейка, которая должна быть очищена. Такой ячейкой может быть любая пустая или та, удаление данных в которой не повредит дальнейшей работе. Естественно, она должна быть незащищенной.

```
Sub Clear_Cell()
Dim r As Range, ur As Range
    Set ur = Cells(1, 1) ' очищаемую ячейку - в формируемый диапазон '

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' проверяем ячейки пользовательского диапазона '
        If Not r.Locked Then Set ur = Union(ur, r) ' незащищенные - в формируеммый диапазон '
    Next r

    ur.ClearContents ' очищам сформированный диапазон '
    Set ur = Nothing ' освобождаем память '
End Sub
```

*Попутно:* не называйте процедуры, переменные и проч. зарезервированными словами. Макрос лучше назвать иначе, например: *Sub Clear_Cell()*.

Если переменной присваивался объект, переменную по окончании работы желательно очистить (*Set ur = Nothing*)

Comment: а почему не сделать просто `For Each c in ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells If Not c.Locked Then c.ClearContents Next c`

Comment: Можно. Но в этом случае при каждой очистке ячейки мы обращаемся к листу, а работа с объектами листа медленная (естественно, на небольшом диапазоне разница очень несущественна). При формировании диапазона очистка происходит за один раз.

Comment: vikttur, спасибо Вам большое. Во-первых я понял, что мой макрос работает если я сам выделю диапазон. Но Ваг вариант куда более удобнее. Но в Вашем коде ошибка, ругается на строку "ur.ClearContents". Пишет, что эта ячейка находится на защищенном листе. Очень благодарен, Эдуарду Измалкову. Убрав из кода "ur.ClearContents" и заменив цикл Вашим, все теперь работает просто идеально. Спасибо большое.

Comment: *Set ur = Cells(1, 1)* - если ячейка *А1* защищена, будет ошибка. Если в создаваемый диапазон поместить незащищенную ячейку, ошибки не должно быть - остальные ячейки, записываемые в диапазон, проверяются в цикле.